# Iterate through list of variables (.net)

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a list of 20 radio buttons that I need to validate (just ensure something is selected) on submission. Is there a easy way to do this in .net or, if necessary, javascript? Radio buttons are all named Rad1, Rad2, Rad3, etc. Thought I'd be able to do it in a simple For/Each and replacing the number with a variable but that definitely doesn't work...

Thanks

Comment: "Radio buttons are all named Rad1, Rad2, Rad3, etc" - that's the problem. Rather than having lots of separate variables, you should have one variable which is a collection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JS/jQuery

```
var isAtleastOneSelected = false;
$('#parentDiv').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    isAtleastOneSelected = true;
    break;
  }
});

if(isAtleastOneSelected) {
  // Atleast one radio btn is selected and continue your work
}
```

Hope this helps